# Mindtouch dekiwiki service crashes on startup (missing assembly error)

Tags: dekiwiki

This is a new install of the Mindtouch Core on Ubuntu 10.04.  I've been following the [Installation Guide](http://developer.mindtouch.com/en/docs/mindtouch_setup/010Installation/050Installing_on_Ubuntu) on the Mindtouch community site.

When I try to start the dekiwiki service, it crashes with the following error:

```
** (/var/www/dekiwiki/bin/mindtouch.host.exe:14465): WARNING **: The following assembly referenced from /var/www/dekiwiki/bin/mindtouch.core.dll could not be loaded:
     Assembly:   System.Web.Routing    (assemblyref_index=2)
     Version:    3.5.0.0
     Public Key: 31bf3856ad364e35
The assembly was not found in the Global Assembly Cache, a path listed in the MONO_PATH environment variable, or in the location of the executing assembly (/var/www/dekiwiki/bin).


** (/var/www/dekiwiki/bin/mindtouch.host.exe:14465): WARNING **: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.

Unhandled Exception: MindTouch.Dream.DreamAbortException: HTTP Status: InternalError(500)

Server stack trace:
  at MindTouch.Dream.DreamHostService+<StartService>d__68.MoveNext () [0x00000]
  at MindTouch.Tasking.Coroutine.Continue () [0x00000]

Exception rethrown at [0]:

  at MindTouch.Dream.DreamHostService+<StartService>d__68.MoveNext () [0x00000]
  at MindTouch.Tasking.Coroutine.Continue () [0x00000]

Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.MulticastDelegate:invoke_void_object_EventArgs (object,System.EventArgs)
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.MulticastDelegate:invoke_void_object_EventArgs (object,System.EventArgs)
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.MulticastDelegate:invoke_void_object_EventArgs (object,System.EventArgs)
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.MulticastDelegate:invoke_void_object_EventArgs (object,System.EventArgs)
  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MindTouch.Tasking.TaskTimerFactory].AddEnumerable (IEnumerable`1 ) [0x00000]
  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MindTouch.Tasking.TaskTimerFactory]..ctor (IEnumerable`1 ) [0x00000]
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TaskTimerFactory] (IEnumerable`1 source) [0x00000]
  at MindTouch.Tasking.TaskTimerFactory.get_Factories () [0x00000]
  at MindTouch.Tasking.TaskTimerFactory.ShutdownAll () [0x00000]
  at MindTouch.Dream.DreamConsoleHost.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000]
```

I've double-checked and I've got Mono 2.10 installed and the System.Web.Routing assembly is definitely there, Mindtouch just isn't finding it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

There's a note at the bottom of the installation instructions that says to check the mono version by running `mono --version`.

Sure enough, `/usr/bin/mono` was still running Mono 1.x.

I did the below to make sure Mono 2.10 was getting run and everything started up like a charm.

```
mv mono mono.old
mv gmcs gmcs.old
ln -s /opt/mono-2.10/bin/mono /usr/bin/mono
ln -s /opt/mono-2.10/bin/gmcs  /usr/bin/gmcs
```